# Clojure accessing static inner class builder expecting var but mapped to class error on build

Tags: java, elasticsearch, clojure, elasticsearch-jest

In Clojure I want to interop to use:

```
JestClientFactory factory = new JestClientFactory();
factory.setHttpClientConfig(new HttpClientConfig
                    .Builder("http://localhost:9200")
                    .build());
```

So I wrote some code like so:

```
 (:import (io.searchbox.client JestClientFactory)
          (io.searchbox.client.config HttpClientConfig$Builder))

 (let [factory (JestClientFactory.)
       http-client-config (-> (HttpClientConfig$Builder "http://localhost:9200")
                           (.build))])
```

But I am getting the following error when building the jar

> Expecting var, but HttpClientConfig$Builder is mapped to class io.searchbox.client.config.HttpClientConfig$Builder

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You lack the `.` behind `HttpClientConfig$Builder`.  Your code does a static call on a class basically.  You need the `new` from your example.

```clj
(-> (HttpClientConfig$Builder. "http://localhost:9200") ; note the `.`
    (.build))
```